# How to call a command over every .json file in a directory with different file extensions?

Tags: bash, npm-scripts, jsonlint

I am trying to write a npm script (bash) to run the command `jsonlint -q` over every .json file in a directory that contains files of other extensions.

This is what I have so far, but it only works for the first json file in the directory. Different things I've tried end up running it over every file regardless of extension.

`ls folder/subfolder/ *.json | xargs jsonlint -q`

Comment: `for x in *.json; do jsonlint -q "$x"; done`. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Use `set -x` beforehand to log commands actually run.

Comment: Is your application ever going to be developed on Windows? If so, you might want to consider a JavaScript solution instead of bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried this, this has no mention of the specific 'folder/subfolder', also I'm putting this as an npm-script - it says that `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '$x'` ... what is the $x supposed to be?

Comment: If you write the `for` loop exactly as @CharlesDuffy wrote in the first comment then the `$x` is the name of each file in the list.  Note that `'` is not the same as `"`.

Comment: Regarding the directory path: just add it to the for loop invocation:  `for x in folder/subfolder/*json; do`